# Org-Mode doesn't export to pdf

Tags: bash, emacs, org-mode

I am using emacs with org mode to take notes. I read that org mode can export to pdf whene you type `C-c C-e lp`. When I type this in, `*Org PDF LaTeX Output*` buffer says :

> /bin/bash: pdflatex: command not found

But when I run `$ pdflatex` on my terminal the program executes.
I belive that emacs doesn't login in bash, and as a result it doesn't have acces to my `$PATH` variable.

Do you have any idea how I can fix this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is pdflatex on your system? What is your $PATH outside of emacs (`echo $PATH` in a shell) and inside Emacs (`(getenv "PATH")`)?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when the Emacs PATH does not copy the contents of the login shell. I run this in the Emacs *scratch* buffer:

```el
(getenv "PATH")
"/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

(Alternatively, hit `M-x` and type `getenv`, then type `PATH`.)

I searched for the location of `pdflatex` in a login shell in Terminal with:

```
> which pdflatex
/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex
```

So I added that directory to the PATH, e.g. add this to `.emacs`:

```el
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/Library/TeX/texbin"))
```

and source it again with `M-x load-file` and type `~/.emacs`. And now `C-c C-e lp` in Org-mode works:

```
PDF file produced.
```

(Cross-posted on [StackOverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117083/problems-with-pdflatex-in-emacs-org-export-as-pdf).)